# SQL ordering with inner join on same table and rename columns

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

The table I want to query, looks something like this:

```
| ------------- ** postmeta ** -------------- |
| unique | post_id  | meta_key   | meta_value |
| --------------------------------------------|
| 1      | 1        | number     | 20         |
| 2      | 2        | number     | 10         |
| 3      | 3        | number     | 30         |
| 4      | 1        | key_a      | xxx        |
| 5      | 2        | key_a      | yyy        |
| 6      | 3        | key_a      | zzz        |
| 7      | 1        | key_b      | aaa        |
| 8      | 2        | key_b      | bbb        |
| 9      | 3        | key_b      | bbb        |
| 10     | 1        | key_c      | 111        |
| 11     | 2        | key_c      | 111        |
| 12     | 3        | key_c      | 222        |
```

**Result wanted**
Given that I wanted to find rows where `key_c = 111` this is what I want to get:

```
| ------------------ ** result ** ------------------ |
| post_id  | time   | other  | another | yet_another |
| ---------------------------------------------------|
| 2        | 10     | yyy    | bbb     | 111         |
| 1        | 20     | xxx    | aaa     | 111         |
```

So, I want to group by `post_id` from rows where `meta_key = key_c AND meta_value = 111` and order by `time`, and rename those columns based on the following cases...

**Pseudo code**
In addition, I would like to select the found `meta_keys` with case statement:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN meta_key = 'number' THEN meta_value END AS 'time'
    CASE WHEN meta_key = 'key_a' THEN meta_value END AS 'other'
    CASE WHEN meta_key = 'key_b' THEN meta_value END AS 'another'
    CASE WHEN meta_key = 'key_c' THEN meta_value END AS 'yet_another'
```

**Current query, which doesn't give me output wanted**

```
SELECT *
FROM postmeta as a
INNER JOIN postmeta as b
    ON a.post_id = b.post_id
WHERE a.meta_key = 'key_c'
    AND a.meta_value = '111'
GROUP BY
    b.post_id
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'number' THEN b.meta_value+(0) ELSE b.post_id END,
    b.post_id
```

Comment: MAX(CASE WHEN blah blah blah...

Comment: @Strawberry sry, i'm a sql newbie, please collaborate

Comment: You're almost there! MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'number' THEN meta_value END) time, etc. Also, your UNIQUE id is redundant. You have a perfectly suitable natural PK on (`post_id`,`meta_key`)

Comment: The way you are storing your data is called the EAV Model (Entity-Attribute-Value) and is an SQL Anti-pattern (because it needs queries like this to display even the simplest of data). I shalln't go through all the arguments for this, there are about [a million articles comparing EAV and the relational model](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eav+model+vs+relational+model). Food for thought though.

Comment: @GarethD this is wordpress related question, so I hope they are listening. :) But yes, could be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your version of the query work by using conditional aggregation without the join.

```
SELECT postid, max(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'number' THEN meta_value END) AS `time`,
       max(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'key_a' THEN meta_value END) AS `other`,
       max(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'key_b' THEN meta_value END) AS `another`,
       max(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'key_c' THEN meta_value END) AS `yet_another`
FROM postmeta pm
GROUP BY pm.post_id
HAVING max(pm.meta_key = 'key_c' AND pm.meta_value = '111') = 1
ORDER BY time desc;
```

Some notes.  A `join` is not strictly needed, which is why I removed it.  It does would be a performance boost if the table is even moderately sized.

Comment: works as it should! thank you! although I needed to convert time to unsigned as it was a srting

Answer (score 0):

Not very flexible but should work for the case you described above:

```
select p.post_id,
n.meta_value as 'time',
a.meta_value as 'other',
b.meta_value as 'another',
c.meta_value as 'yet_another'
from postmeta p
left outer join
(
select t.post_id,t.meta_value
from postmeta t
where meta_key = 'number'
) n on n.post_id = p.post_id
left outer join
(
select t.post_id,t.meta_value
from postmeta t
where meta_key = 'key_a'
) a on a.post_id = p.post_id
left outer join
(
select t.post_id,t.meta_value
from postmeta t
where meta_key = 'key_b'
) b on b.post_id = p.post_id
left outer join
(
select t.post_id,t.meta_value
from postmeta t
where meta_key = 'key_c'
) c on c.post_id = p.post_id
where p.meta_key = 'key_c'
and p.meta_value = '111'
order by `time` asc
;
```

Comment: Wow, never thought this would be that complex query